# How do you grab an attribute of child node in XML

Tags: xml, dom, vbscript

I'm looking for a method to grab the an attribute of a child node from the parent node. So far I have:

```vb
For each dataNodedsd in xmlDocBindings.SelectNodes("//dataobject")
    nodesDsdID = dataNodedsd.getAttribute("objectid")
    set parentNode = dataNodedsd.parentNode
    if d.Exists(nodesDsdID) Then
        d.item(nodesDsdID) = parentNode.getAttribute("ID") 
        paramstr = parentnode.selectsinglenode("property[@name='pointrefparamname']").text 
        msgbox paramStr
        d2key = parentNode.getAttribute("ID")

        'add ids to dict2

        d2.add d2key, ""
    End If
```

I am currently looking to pull paramstr from the parent node. My current attempt was using the code provided

```vb
paramstr = parentnode.selectsinglenode("property[@name='pointrefparamname']").text
```

However I am failing to properly pull the string from the node.

This is a sample of XML that I am attempting to pull from the node:

```
<dataobject format="propertybag" type="HMIPage.Generic" id="3">

<property name="AddressFlags">1</property>

<property name="AddressType">0</property>

<property name="CalloutElement"/>

<property name="ObjectType">0</property>

<property name="ParameterFormat">0</property>

<property name="PointRefFlags">0</property>

<property name="PointRefParamName">PIDA.MODEFL.CAS</property>

<property name="PointRefParamOffset">0</property>

<property name="PointRefPointName">00FC1627</property>

<property name="PresentationType">0</property>

<property name="SecurityLevel">0</property>

<property name="UpdatePeriod">0</property>

<property name="version">1.3</property>

</dataobject>
```

I am simply trying to pull from

```xml
<property name="PointRefParamName">PIDA.MODEFL.CAS</property>
```

and get the result

```
PIDA.MODEFL.CAS
```

as a string. So far everything I have looked up either hasn't been working(either to my incompetence/misunderstanding or lack of viable methodology. If anyone could clear this up it would be greatly appreciated. Once again I am simply attempting to grab an attribute from a child node within a parent node.

Comment: not sure this is the issue but in this line nodesDsdID = dataNodedsd.getAttribute("objectid") ... there is no attribute "objectid" on the "dataobject" tag.

Comment: It is just extra code from another XML that I had to pull information and compare to this XML

Comment: Next issue I see is you are comparing for "pointrefparamname" but thge name is actually "PointRefParamName" ... case matters in XML

Comment: Yes this is a later iteration of me basically smashing my keyboard, however after changing to correct casing still not the desired output only  a blank msgbox.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in VBA

```vb
Sub getValXml()
  Dim myDocument As DOMDocument30
  Dim parNodes As IXMLDOMNodeList
  Dim parNode As IXMLDOMNode
  Dim myNode As IXMLDOMNode
  Set myDocument = New DOMDocument30

  myDocument.Load ("C:\temp\text.xml")
  Set parNodes = myDocument.SelectNodes("//dataobject")
  For Each parNode In parNodes
    Set myNode = parNode.SelectSingleNode("property[@name='PointRefParamName']")
    MsgBox myNode.Text
  Next
End Sub
```

The output is [image]

Comment: The question is asking for a VBScript solution, posting VBA answers *(while correct)* just complicates things. It doesn't take much to modify this solution to VBScript just remove the use of Types *(as VBScript is Type-less)* and you should be somewhere close.

Comment: Sorry, I was going from the title (which says VBA) and not the tag.